# Visual Studio error message: NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll is missing

Tags: visual-studio, nunit-3.0, nunittestadapter

I have an issue with Visual Studio and NUnit Test Adapter which I cannot find the answer for. Every morning and sometimes during the day, when I try to build my solution I get an error message that the dll under NUnit3TestAdapter folder is missing:

> ...\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.10.0\build\net35\NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll

The only way to fix it (temporarily) is to close and reopen Visual Studio.
Any idea why this is happening all of a sudden and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into a similar problem and found your post. I wasn't able to get it going again just by closing and reopening, but the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526149/how-to-fix-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-nunit-engine-version-3-7-0-0) seems to point to a known bug, and deleting the folder it mentions did get me back up and running again, might be worth trying that.